# node.js request(get) result return

Tags: node.js, request

I want to return the result obtained from the request.

The code does not produce the desired result.

Please help me

CODE

```
const getData = async (gn) => {
  let gameData = undefined;

  gameData = await rq({
    method: "GET",
    url: base_url + "/get_gameData/OXquiz",
  }).then(function (response) {
    return response;
  });

  return gameData;
};

console.log(getData("OXquiz"));
```

RESULT

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

The result I want

```
{"status":0,"message":[{"ga_win_point":"100","ga_lose_point":"50","ga_time":"10","ga_max_number":"8"}],"url":""}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). TL;DR you want `getData("OXquiz").then(console.log)`

Comment: Your entire function can be simplified to `const getData => (gn) => rq({ method: "GET", url: \`${base_url}/get_gameData/${gn}\` })`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
getData().then(item => console.log(item))
```

or

```
const data = await getData()
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using await and .then at a time. If you want to work asynchronously use the following snippet.

```
const getData = async (gn) => {
  let gameData = undefined;

  gameData = await rq({
    method: "GET",
    url: base_url + "/get_gameData/OXquiz",
  });

  return gameData;
};

console.log(getData("OXquiz"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I ran that code and still get "Promise { <pending>}" result. ㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠ